# toggle div on and off produces random results

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a simple content toggle. When I click it now, the first 3 divs toggle at once, but none of the others.

I am not targeting the div correctly and need some help with that.

I need to somehow pass the div id through the function:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
export default function Page( {page, releases} ) {

  const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);
  function toggle(){
    setShowMe(!showMe);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
       
        <ContainerContent>
          <Container>
              <Row>

                {releases.nodes 
                  && releases.nodes.map((press) => (

                  <Col xs={12} md={6} key={press.databaseID} id={press.databaseID}>
        
                    <h2 onClick={toggle} id={press.databaseID}>{press.title}</h2>
                    <div 
                      id={press.databaseID}
                      style={{ display: showMe ? "block" : "none" }}>
    
                      <a href={press.pressreleases.calloutLink}
                        className="press-link"  
                        target="_blank"
                        >{press.pressreleases.calloutLinkText}</a>

                      <div className="date-format">
                        <Date dateString={press.date} />
                      </div>
    
                    </div>
        
                  </Col>

                  ), [])}
    
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </ContainerContent>

      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you want to toggle your divs individually the easiest way will be to wrap `h2` and `div` in a separate component with toggle logic inside it

Comment: HI Nadia, how would that look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have one flag to toggle multiple elements

```
 const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);
```

This will only work if you want to show and hide them all at once. So you either need to replace it with an array of flags, or encapsulate this logic in a different component, which is arguably a bit cleaner and it will look something like this:

```
function PressRelease( {press} ) {
    const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);
    function toggle(){
      setShowMe(showMe => !showMe);
    }
    return (<>
        <h2 onClick={toggle}    id={press.databaseID}>{press.title}</h2>
                                    <div 
                                            id={press.databaseID}
                                            style={{
                                            display: showMe?"block":"none"
                                          }}>
  
                                            <a href={press.pressreleases.calloutLink}
                                                className="press-link"  
                                                target="_blank"
                                                >{press.pressreleases.calloutLinkText}</a>

                                            <div className="date-format">
                                                  <Date dateString={press.date} />
                                                </div>
  
                                        </div></>)}

 function Page( {page, releases} ) {
   ...
  return (
   ...
   {releases.nodes && releases.nodes.map((press) => (

                        <Col xs={12} md={6} key={press.databaseID} id={press.databaseID}>
  <PressRelease press={press} />
```

Comment: thats way better than what I had, thank you!  For anyone else looking, your PressRelease needs a fragment

Comment: Oops, that what happens when you code in a textbox! Glad I could help though :)